# Destructor not finding my namespace method

Tags: c++

main.cpp:

```
#include "headerone.hpp"

int main() {
    menus::menu();
}
```

headerone.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "headertwo.hpp"

namespace menus {
    void menu() {
       object instance;
    }
}
```

headertwo.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "headerone.hpp"

class object {
public:
    object() {
       method();
    }

    void method() {
        int x; /* do something */
    }

    ~object() {
        menus::menu();
    }
};
```

I get an error in the deconstructor saying that menu namespace cannot be found.

**Error C2653   'menu': is not a class or namespace name**

Comment: So, headerone includes headertwo, which includes headerone, which includes headertwo... Do you see how there's a cycle here? Thankfully, with `pragma once` you don't get an infinite inclusion loop, but you still get that error.

Comment: how it would be possible without a cycle? i need headertwo in header one, and headerone in headertwo.

Comment: Move the implementation of `menu()` out of headerone.hpp and into headerone.cpp.  The implementation should not be *defined* in a header file, only the function signature should be *declared*.

Comment: You mean to make a header file with the function signature, then define it in a cpp file? then include that header file?

Comment: Setting the `include`s issue aside, you have a running infinite construction/destruction going on: https://godbolt.org/z/38GhPzoY3

Answer (score 4):

The `menu()` function should only be *declared* in the header file.  The *definition* should be in its associated .cpp source file.

The **headerone.hpp** file should look like this:

```
#pragma once

namespace menus {

void menu();

} // menus
```

The **headerone.cpp** file should look like this:

```
#include "headerone.hpp"
#include "headertwo.hpp"

namespace menus {

void menu() {
   object instance;
}

} // menus
```

One of the areas that *many* good C++ books omit are how source files, header files, and projects should be put together.  There is one good — albeit rather long in the tooth (but still relevant) — book called **Large-Scale C++ Software Design** by John Lakos which discusses project layout and suggested implementation in great detail.

He also has a more recent book in two volumes called **Large-Scale C++**, which is not a replacement for the earlier book.  Rather it has an even broader and more ambitious scope for software development.  Volume I is **Process and Architecture**, and Volume II is **Design and Implementation**.

Answer (score 3):

You have **cyclic dependency** in your program.

You can **solve** this by using **source files**(*.cpp*) in addition to **header files**(*.hpp*) as shown below:

**headerone.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "headertwo.hpp"

namespace menus {
    void menu(); //this is a declaration
}
```

**headerone.cpp**

```
#include "headerone.hpp"
namespace menus
{
//this is a definition
void menu() {
       object instance;
}
}
```

**headertwo.hpp**

```
#pragma once

//no need to include headerone.hpp here

class object {
public:
    object() {
       method();
    }

    void method() {
        int x; /* do something */
    }

    ~object();//this is a declaration
};
```

**headertwo.cpp**

```
#include "headertwo.hpp"
#include "headerone.hpp"
object::~object() {
        menus::menu();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "headerone.hpp"
#include "headertwo.hpp"
int main() {
    menus::menu();
}
```

The output of the above modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/LUPmcJHFf).